# How can I use mapbox in JSQMessagesViewController swift

Tags: swift, mapbox, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

How can i display a Mapbox map in a JSQMessagesViewController bubble in swift? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a class which conforms JSQMessageMediaData protocol to create your media data

Code:

```
import JSQMessagesViewController

class ProductChatMsg: NSObject, JSQMessageMediaData {
func mediaView() -> UIView! {
    let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("XXView", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! UIView

    return view
}

func mediaViewDisplaySize() -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 228, height: 156)
}

func mediaPlaceholderView() -> UIView! {
    return UIView()
}

func mediaHash() -> UInt {
    return UInt(self.hash)
}
}
```